# To make a specific line from a set of lines bold in a textbox/listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a specific line in textbox/listbox bold in C# . net and not the entire box contents ok.

Below is the example, consider that these all are displayed in text/list box,

> Hi 
>   **Hello**
>   How are you

You could note that hello is bolded, this is what I need to achieve.
Kindly help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform is it? WPF, WinForms, WinRT?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Its windows form application in C#

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to achieve this.

there is a constructor for Font class which takes following 3 attributes:

**1.FontFamily**  : you can assign any specific font family if you want , otherwise just provide the current TextBox font Family.

**2.Font Size:** you can assign any specific font sie as a `float` number if you want , otherwise just provide the current TextBox font size.

**3.Font Style:** there are basically different Font Styles are available.

Like Regular,Bold,Italic,Underline,Strikeout.

You need to send `FontStyle.Bold` to make your text Bold.

From MSDN :

> Defines a particular format for text, including font face, size, and
>   **style** attributes. This class cannot be inherited.

Try This:

```
Font font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, textBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
textBox1.Font = font;
```

**EDIT:** as you said in below comments , if you want to make the only part of the text as `BOLD` its not possible in `TextBox`

From `@Stephan` coments :

but in `ListBox` it is possible if you use `DrawItem` event.

See Here : [DrawEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)

as an alternative You can use `RichTextBox`

**Solution 2:** Making part of Text Bold in `RichTextBox`

if you are using `RichTextBox` control you can use `SelectionFont` property to make only selected Text bold (or whatever font you want to apply)

```
Font font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, richTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = font;
```

Comment: Hi, Your code makes the entire text box contents bold, that is not what i want, I need only specific lines.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I achieve using Rich Text Box

Comment: @RajaVignesh: check my edited answer with `solution 2`

Comment: *if you want to make the only part of the text as BOLD its not possible* - that's not exactly true :-) You can use the `DrawItem` event

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution...

The only list-type Control in Windows Forms that supports setting the `Font` property for each Item is the `ListView`. Try this:

1. put a `ListView` on the Form. Set its `View` property to `Details`.
2. edit the ListView `Columns` collection: add one Column; set that Column's width so its contents will be clearly visible.

```
// define two font-faces, one bold
private Font font1 = new Font("Arial",9.0F, FontStyle.Regular);
private Font font2 = new Font("Arial",9.0F, FontStyle.Bold);

// demonstrate adding Items to ListView

private void AddListViewItems()
{
  // add ten Items
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var lvItem = new ListViewItem("item " + i.ToString());

    // make every other item use the bold font-face
    lvItem.Font = (i % 2 == 0) ? font1 : font2;

    listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `ListBox`, you can accomplish that by drawing the items yourself.

Set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and handle the `DrawItem`-event. Here you can specify the the `Font` that is used. As mentioned in another answer, you can set `FontStyle.Bold`

[MSDN-Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)